# Rig shoes composed of multiple parts

Tags: rigging, rigify

I am relatively new too blender and finished a model i want to animate now.

The rig is working (i used rigify) and i managed to rig/parent the clothing as well (pants/tshirt).

But i am struggling to find a way to rig the shoes so they can deform with the rig, as the are composed of multiple objetcs (rivtes, laces, mesh etc)

I tried to join all the objects before parenting with auto weight and it still does not work.
The differents object behave independently (see screenshot)
I tried the data transfer method and nothing moves.

Whats would be the ideal worflow to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Shoes]
[image: deformed shoes]
[image: Transfer]

Answer (score 1):

look this! will help you
https://youtu.be/1WS8b1Ww8Ys

if your model has a foot attached to the rest of the body ... you can do the same procedure, and use the data transfer on the deformation object

Comment: great solution using a mesh deform modfier!

Comment: actually, what do you mean by "if a foot is attached...". I do a have a foot attached to my body model and I sometimes run into a situation where the rig's deformation causes my foot to look through the shoe, because mesh deformation on the shoe and armature deformation around the foot area are quite different probably... do you have a solution to this?